# I want to add a check to all my commands in discord.py. Is there a shortcut way to do so?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to add a same check before all my commands in discord.py. I have to do it in each and every command. Is there a way that i can add that check only once for all commands??.

Example:

```
@commands.command(name="ping")
async def _ping(self,ctx):
    db = firebase.database()
    isEnabled = db.child('Disabled').child(str(ctx.guild.id)).child(ctx.command).get()
    if isEnabled.val() is None:
        lat = round((self.bot.latency)*1000)
        if lat < 150:
            em = discord.Embed(title=":ping_pong: | Pong!",description=f":green_circle: Current Latency : `{lat}`ms",color=discord.Color.green())
        elif lat >= 150:
            em = discord.Embed(title=":ping_pong: | Pong!",description=f":yellow_circle: Current Latency : `{lat}`ms",color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255,255,0))  
        else:
            em = discord.Embed(title=":ping_pong: | Pong!",description=f":red_circle: Current Latency : `{lat}`ms",color=discord.Color.red())
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
    else:
        em = discord.Embed(description="This command is disabled in your server. Ask admin to enable it",color=discord.Color.random())
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Here i check if the command is disabled or not first, as i have to do this same thing in each command is there another way to do so, apart from what i am doing??

Pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `bot.check` decorator that will apply to all your commands

Example:

```py
@bot.check
async def globally_block_dms(ctx):
    return ctx.guild is not None # no dms
```

You can check if the command is disabled by using ctx.guild and ctx.guild.id